# пинг с помощью InetAddress

Tags: java, сеть, java-8

Хочу сделать программу простую, которая пингует сервера. Работает так: InetAddress.getByName("123.123.123.123") и замеряю время с помощью System.currentTimeMills(). Проблема в том, что когда делаю замеры на пингующем сервере, получаю большое время пинга, но последующие запуски программы показывают малое время. Я полагаю, что эти замеры как-то кэшируются, либо к серверу компьютер быстро подключается. В общем вопрос такой почему так происходит?

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName("68.251.250.193");
        a.getHostName();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
        InetAddress x = InetAddress.getByName("104.128.206.123");
        x.getHostName();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - m);
    }
}
```

Comment: `InetAddress.getByName()` не пингует адрес, а делает запросы к DNS, результаты которых кэшируются, естественно.

Comment: А можно этот кэш сбромсить?

Comment: Или как-нибудь по-другому пингануть?

Comment: Кэширование dns-ответов можно отключить на уровне операционной системы, но от этого `InetAddress.getByName()` не станет пинговать хосты, он для этого не предназначен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [InetAddress.isReachable()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable-int-) для проверки доступности сервера.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

class Main {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;

    private static boolean ping(String addr) {
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(addr);
            return address.isReachable(TIMEOUT);
        } catch (IOException exc){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (ping("68.251.250.193"))
            System.out.println("Сервер доступен");
        else
            System.out.println("Сервер недоступен");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
    }
}
```